# Android mute button

Tags: android, keycode, mute

Some new Android devices have a mute button like Iphone.  Its an actual physical button that allows you to mute an incoming call instead of long pressing the volume down hardware control or the pressing the power button.

my question:  What is the keycode event for this or how can i capture it so i can get my app to respond to it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MUTE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MUTE). Note that no flagship Android devices have this button, so you are left to the mercy of whether or not the manufacturer's OS actually sends this event or not.

Comment: ill check out if this is what i want on my co-workers device and respond here in a day or two.

Comment: KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE vs     KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MUTE    ...i dont know which one it is that gets triggered when the physical mute button on some new androids.  As far as i can read  is first is for the speakers and  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MUTE is for the mic but which one gets called when the phsyical mute button is tapped.  It could be while the phones in speaker mode then KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE gets called but with no documentation im guessing here.  Can anyone test it and let me know, im working blind here without a device that has this hardware.

Comment: It would depend on the features of the OS on the device. If the mute button mutes the mic, it should be `KEYCODE_MUTE`. If it mutes the speakers, it should be `KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE`. Either way, you should obtain access to one of these devices for a test run before you implement your app.

Comment: turns out my co-worker was talking about the power button being used to mute the incoming call ring not a seperate mute button.

Comment: Then that's not a key event. You may have to run some kind of service to catch a sound change, if that's even possible. I'm really not sure.